# Flutter Getx rebuild not working while using getters as observables

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

Initialized the observable with getter:

```
RxString get _currentRoute => _routeService.currentRoute.obs;
```

Updating the currentRoute inside RootService changes the value of _currentRoute but doesn't update the widget.

```
_routeService.update(route);
```

Tried update using refresh() also doesn't work.

```
_currentRoute.refresh();
```

The GetView part:

```
Obx(() => _getPage(controller.currentRoute)),
```

Comment: Your approach seems totally wrong to me. Not sure what you want to achieve. But appending `.obs` to another objects variable and try to update that variable won't do anything.

Comment: Thank you. I got it

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
void updateString() {
   _routeService.update(route);
}
```

The instance you get from the getter is not the original thing but the mere copy of it. That's why performing any operation on its copy won't change the original one. Hence, no update in the widget.

Comment: This won't make any difference